# call the same jQuery function in multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not really familiar with jQuery. I have this code that I downloaded to create a fade in/fade out popup form. Here's the code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button').click(function(e) { 
            $('#modal').reveal({ 
                animation: 'fade',
                animationspeed: 150,
                closeonbackgroundclick: true, 
                dismissmodalclass: 'close'
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code above executes when a button with an `id='button'` is clicked. Now I have multiple buttons, how can I call this function in all buttons? I tried setting the `id` of all buttons to `button` but only the first button works. Any help would be very much appreciated. 
By the way I forgot to mention, in my .php file i have this codes:

```
for ($c=1;$c<=5;$c++){
echo "<input type='button' id='button'">
};
```

This php code will display 5 buttons with the same id which is 'button'. What I want to happen is when I click any of the 5 buttons the jQuery function will execute which is popping up a fade in/fade out form.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**First solution :**

```
function doClick(e) { 
   $('#modal').reveal({ 
     animation: 'fade',
     animationspeed: 150,
     closeonbackgroundclick: true, 
     dismissmodalclass: 'close'
   });
   return false;
}
$('#button1').click(doClick);
$('#button2').click(doClick);
```

**Second solution :**

Give a class "someClass" to all the involved buttons

```
<input type=button class=someClass ...
```

and do

```
$('.someClass').click(function(e) { 
...
});
```

**Third solution :**

Use the comma to separate ids :

```
$('#button1, #button2').click(function(e) { 
...
});
```

---

Generally, the best solution is the second one : it allows you to add buttons in your code without modifying the javascript part. If you add some of those buttons dynamically, you may even do

```
$(document).on('click', '.someClass', function(e) { 
...
});
```

Comment: +1 nice overview of the different ways of achieving the same thing

Comment: Bravo! Bravo! Bravo! Thank you so much @dystroy, you're a genius. I used your 2nd solution and it perfectly works.

Answer (score 1):

Use different ids for buttons and change your function as below.

> $('#button1, #button2, #button3').click(function(e) {
>   
> .....

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be unique. Try using something like

```
$('input[type="button"]')
```

Comment: A class would be better suited IMO

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan As long as a container with an ID isnt specified, I would say it doesnt make that much of a difference. Just wanted to post an alternative to the other answers

Answer (score 0):

you class can call them by class you using `,` seperated id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button, #button1, #button2').click(function(e) { 
$('#modal').reveal({ 
animation: 'fade',
animationspeed: 150,
closeonbackgroundclick: true, 
dismissmodalclass: 'close'
});
return false;
});
});​
```

Comment: this should work, but I have 5 buttons with the same id generated from  loop inside php file. Or is it possible naming a button id with an array, like button id='button[0]'?

Comment: for that it is better to use class

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button1,#button2,#button3').click(function(e) { 
$('#modal').reveal({ 
animation: 'fade',
animationspeed: 150,
closeonbackgroundclick: true, 
dismissmodalclass: 'close'
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

or else use class as mentioned bt dystroy

Answer (score 0):

You can use **css class name** instead of `id` to achieve it like below

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fade').click(function(e) { 
        $('#modal').reveal({ 
            animation: 'fade',
            animationspeed: 150,
            closeonbackgroundclick: true, 
            dismissmodalclass: 'close'
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and your html of the buttons

```
<button class="fade">Button1</button>
<button class="fade">Button2</button>
<button class="fade">Button3</button>
```

Comment: What if the class attribute has multiple values supplied e.g. class="class1 class2 class3" etc?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use same  buttonid  for  all button then there is no  need to call all buttons..just simply use this code..It seems that you are using animation in this code....well use **togglefade** instead of reveal

> `<script type=text/javascript>
>        $(document).ready(function(){
>           $("button").click(function(){
>              $("#buttonid").fadein();
>              $("#buttonid").fadeout();
>      });
>     });
>   </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Create an array for unique buttonid dynamically in the loop like

```
$button[] = '#'.$buttonid;
```

Outside the loop use `implode` to convert this array to comma separated string

```
$jsstring = implode(",",$button);
```

Now use php to pass above string as selector in your js code like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('< php echo $jsstring ; ?>').click(function(){ });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the easier simple ways as following code :

Method 1:

> ```
> <script>
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         $('input:button[name="button1"],[name="button2"]').click(
>             function () {
>                 alert('test')
>             });
>     });
> </script>
> <input type="button" id="button1" name="button1" value="Filter" />
> <input type="button" id="button2" name="button2" value="Filter" />
> ```

Method 2:

> ```
> <script>
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         $('button[id="button1"],[id="button2"]').click(
>             function () {
>                 alert('te2222st')
>             });
>     });
> </script>
> <button id="button1" >bbbbb</button>
> <button id="button2" >bbbbb</button>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for this problem

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#btnSubmit,#btnSubmitbuttom").click(function () {
                        var rfp = true;
                        var count = 0;
                        var lbxBD_Role = $("#lbxBD_Role option:selected").val();
                        if (lbxBD_Role == "" || lbxBD_Role == undefined) {
                            $("#lblBD_Role").attr("style", "visibility: visible");
                            $("#lblBD_Role").attr("style", "color: red");
                            $("#lblBD_Role").html('* Required');
                            count++;
                        }
                      });
                   });
            </script>
```