# Do the same thing on multiple button presses

Tags: c#

I have 50 buttons on my form and want them to add +1 to a int called number whenever they are pressed

Except for 1 button that I want to add +2 to number

How can I do this without having the same code repeated for 49 buttons?

Comment: Have you even tried searching for a solution?

Comment: Add the buttons to an array or loop through the array of controls on the form (using the `Controls` collection assuming this is `WinForms`) and subscribe the event handler for each using a loop. You can handle the exception manually

Comment: Use script code to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083106/call-the-same-jquery-function-in-multiple-buttons

Comment: I would really like to see the form of that application! Maybe hes a troll :-P

Answer (score 4):

You would need an event to handle each buttons `click`. In here you would increment the `number`. I'd iterate over all of the forms controls and if they're a `Button`, add the event.

You would obviously want to handle the case where the button needs to +2, but that's easy enough when you look at the buttons `Name` attribute.

Something like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Button))
        {
            Button btn = (Button)ctrl;

            if (btn.Name == "ADD TWO")
            {
                btn.Click += btn_Click_Add_Two;
            }
            else
            {
                btn.Click += btn_Click_Add_One;
            }
        }
    }
}

void btn_Click_Add_One(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Number++;
}

void btn_Click_Add_Two(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Number += 2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void SetClickEvents()
{
    // Add the listeners
    btn1.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
    btn2.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
    btn3.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
    // ... repeat for 49, or even loop

}

void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // DO your adding
}
```