# Getting Data from button click for Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the "Second Solution" from this problem:
[call the same jQuery function in multiple buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083106/call-the-same-jquery-function-in-multiple-buttons)

I am dynamically creating my buttons, based on an input, so there is currently 45 buttons! (used to select page number)

Is there a way to use the value of the button as data in my `$.get` so I can pull the data for the page?

```
$('.bclick').click(function(){
    $.getJSON("url", { page: [need button data here] }, function(data){
        //Some actionable code
    })
});
```

`.bclick` is the class given to each of the buttons created.

Comment: what exactly button's data you need?

Comment: Would `this.value` not work?

Comment: Preferably the button's "value", the visual text inside the button (as it only states the page value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are inside of the `function`, the reserved word `this` is a reference to your clicked `button`.

```
$('.bclick').click(function(){
    var page = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON("url", { page: page }, function(data){
        //Some actionable code
    })
});
```

If your buttons are created dinamically probably this solution won't work. I may suggest you to use `$.on()`:

```
$("parent selector or form selector").on("click", ".bclick", function(){
    var page = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON("url", { page: page }, function(data){
        //Some actionable code
    })
})
```

Comment: Nevermind, I accidentally deleted "page: " so it was clueless why the value was there!

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating buttons dynamically, then use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".blick", function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var buttonName = $this.attr("name");
    });
});
```

[Sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsadasivan/w0goj9v9/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by adding an extra attribute to your .bclick element, for example 
`<button class="bclick" data="your data here"></button>`.

Then

```
$('.bclick').click(function(){
    var buttonData = $(this).attr('data');
$.getJSON("url", { page: buttonData }, function(data){
   //Some actionable code
   })
});
```